# Disc burning software that can finalize discs after burning them

Tags: windows, gratis, optical-media

I need a program that can finalize a cd/dvd after data has been burned to it. A finalized disc will prevent any additional data from being written to it.

I'm not looking to burn .iso files to the disc, rather I'm burning individual files then finalizing the disc so the files can't be altered and no more files can be written.

Windows 7 does not have this feature built in. The functionality described in [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/close-finalize-cd-dvd#1TC=windows-7) is not what I am looking for.

I'm currently using Roxio Creator for this task, but I'm looking for an alternative due to problems with the Roxio software.

Is there any free software that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ISO Burner](http://www.freeisoburner.com/)

- free
- Microsoft Windows XP/2003/Vista/Windows 7/Windows 8
- can finalize disks after burning

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that tool only seems to burn .iso files. I'd like to be able to burn individual files to the disc without creating a disc image file first.

Comment: OK you might consider adding this explicitly as a requirement then :)

Answer (score 1):

I really like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).

- Runs on ***pretty much* ALL Windows* - not 3.1 though (starts working in Windows 95) (and I've tried it in most Windows version since then). Compatible with Linux through Wine (though I haven't tried that personally).
- You can select a combination of files or folders or image files.
- Burns DVD player compatible DVD-Video.
- Free.
- Quite powerful if you want but very easy if you just want to quickly burn stuff.